# Using output piped from sed

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a sed command that is capturing a single line with sometext. The line in the file it is capturing ends with a linefeed. I am trying to utilize this variable in a pipeline, however, when I attempt to echo, or use it with other commands requiring an input, the result is a blank. Ex:
`sed '1,1!d' somefile.txt | echo "$1"`,  I know the variable itself is not empty as I can replace `echo "$1"` with `cat $1` and see the correct printout.

edit - I have tried piping to a tr -d and removing the newline. I have confirmed the newline character is gone, yet echos still show blank. Cats do not.

edit 2 - I piped the variable into an if statement `... | if [[ -z $1 ]]; then cat $1; fi` it hits the if, is determined to be empty, so runs the cat, which prints a non-empty line to console. If the variable is empty why is cat still printing out information?

What is causing this inconsistency and how can I solve my problem? The ultimate goal is to run the output of one sed, through another to replace specific lines in a target file.

`sed '1,1!d' somefile.txt | sed '2,1s/.*/'$1'/' targetfile.txt`

### Contents of somefile.txt:

```
these
are
words
```

### Contents of targetfile.txt:

```
The next line should say these
This line should say these
The previous line should say these
```

Output of echo after sed:

```
<empty>
```

Output of cat after sed:

```
these
```

Output of 2nd sed, using input from 1st:

```
The next line should say these

the previous line should say these
```

Comment: What do you mean create a sample you can test? I have described my process completely. im taking a line from a file that literally contains 3 lines of gibberish while running my own tests. Do you really need me to describe the contents of a gibberish test file? I am simply running the command `sed'1,1!d' somefile.txt | echo "$1"` , `sed'1,1!d' somefile.txt | sed '1,1s/.*/'$1'/' FileToChange.txt"` and `sed'1,1!d' somefile.txt | cat $1` where the contents of somefile.txt are these\n are\n words\n (each word being its own line of course) As stated, Cat is the only one that prints non blank lines.

Comment: I don't mean to sound crass, but everything I just stated is in the question I asked. I don't know how I'm supposed to give you the output after the first sed, or the intermediate output, Because I have already stated, it is blank when not used in cat. Can you please better explain what is unclear?

Comment: @Erudaki we do not need you to **describe** the contents of a gibberish test file, we need you to **show us** the contents of a test file, gibberish or otherwise. Words are ambiguous - we need a concrete [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and execpected output that helps demonstrate your problem and which we can test a potential solution against to see if it works or not. Also, right now your asking us for help to fix the syntax of what you think is the solution to your problem not how to solve your problem correctly, i.e. it sounds like an XY Problem. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: @Erudaki, why are you using `$1`?

Comment: @Erudaki please select your sample data and click the `{}` editing icon or press `ctrl+k`... you do not need to use `\n`... for the given `somefile.txt` and `targetfile.txt`, could you please add what is expected output? I'm still not clear what is your requirement (and not sure if you know [what $1 means](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables))

Comment: examples of question with sample input data, expected output nicely formatted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870285/reverse-four-length-of-letters-with-sed-in-unix and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920626/sort-rows-in-csv-file-without-header-first-column

Comment: @Erudaki since you did put the effort into providing some sample input/output, I took a shot at fixing the formatting of it for you. Please check it and fix any mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused about arguments and input data. Look at this:

```
$ echo "$1"

$ echo "foo" | if [[ -z $1 ]]; then cat $1; fi
foo
```

The first argument to my shell, `$1` is empty so `if [[ -z $1 ]]` succeeds. The reason that `cat $1` produces output is that you have a fundamental shell programming error in that statement - you aren't quoting your variable, `$1`. The correct syntax isn't `cat $1`, it's `cat "$1"`. Look at the difference:

```
$ echo "foo" | if [[ -z $1 ]]; then cat "$1"; fi
cat: '': No such file or directory
```

We can simplify the code to make what's happening clearer:

```
$ echo "foo" | cat $1
foo

$ echo "foo" | cat "$1"
cat: '': No such file or directory
```

The reason that `echo "foo" | cat $1` produces output is that the unquoted $1 is expanded by the shell to nothing before `cat` is called so that statement is equivalent to just `echo "foo" | cat` and so cat just copies the input coming in from the pipe to it's output.

On the other hand `echo "foo" | cat "$1"` generates an error because the shell expands `"$1"` to the null string before cat is called and so it's then asking cat to open a file named `<null>` and that of course does not exist, hence the error.

Always quote your shell variables unless you have a specific reason not to and fully understand all of the implications. Read a shell man page and/or google that if you're not sure what those implications are.

wrt another part of your code you have:

```
sed '1,1!d' somefile.txt | echo "$1"
```

but, unlike `cat`, `echo` neither reads it's input from a pipe nor from a file name passed as an argument. The input to echo is just the list of string arguments you provide it so while `echo "foo" | cat` will cause cat to read the input stream containing `foo` and output it, `echo "foo" | echo` will produce no output because `echo` isn't designed to read input from a pipe and so it'll just print a null string since you gave it no arguments.

It's not clear what you're really trying to accomplish but I **think** you might want to replace the 2nd line of `targetfile.txt` with the first line of `somefile.txt`. If so that's just:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { if (NR==1) new=$0; next }
    FNR==2  { $0 = new }
    { print }
' somefile.txt targetfile.txt
```

Do not try to use sed to do it or you'll find yourself in escaping/quoting hell because, unlike awk, sed does not understand literal strings, see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to extract the first line from `file1` and use it to replace the second line in `file2`.

At the moment, you are extracting that value from the first file with your first `sed` but sending it to the second `sed` on its `stdin` rather than as a parameter (`$1`).

Your description is confusing so I will use this as `file1`:

```
File 1 Line 1
File 1 Line 2
File 1 Line 3
```

And this as `file2`:

```
File 2 Line 1
File 2 Line 2
File 2 Line 3
```

There are many ways to do this.

---

**Method 1**

```
# Extract line1 from file1
extracted=$(sed '1!d' file1)
# Replace line 2 in file2 with extracted value
sed "2s/.*/$extracted/" file2
```

Not sure why I feel like a dentist now :-)

If you want to put it all on one line, as some folks like to do:

```
x=$(sed '1!d' file1) && sed "2s/.*/$x/" file2
```

---

**Method 2**

This one is a bit tricky. It uses the first `sed` to write a script for the second `sed`:

```
sed  's/^/2s|.*|/;s/$/|/;q' file1 | sed -f /dev/stdin file2
```

If you look at the first `sed` on its own you will see it is generating a script for the second one:

```
sed  's/^/2s|.*|/;s/$/|/;q' file1
2s|.*|File 1 Line 1|
```

If you look at the second `sed`, you will see it is executing a script passed on its *standard input*:

```
sed -f /dev/stdin ...
```

---

**Method 3**

Easier still is `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if(NR==1)saved=$0;next} FNR==2{$0=saved}1' file1 file2
File 2 Line 1
File 1 Line 1
File 2 Line 3
```

All you need to notice is that I am passing 2 files to `awk` and that `FNR==NR` inside the script means that `awk` is currently processing the first file, because FNR is the line number in the current file and NR is the total number of lines `awk` has processed from all files so far. So, when processing the second file, NR is greater than FNR by the number of lines in the first file.